# Setting up Amazon S3/Github pipeline for static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, continuous-integration, aws-codepipeline

I have a github repo for a static website. It's a simple project structure with a `dist/` and a `src/` folder at the root and the `index.html` for the site is at `dist/index.html`. I'm trying to host it in an Amazon S3 bucket.

I set up an AWS CodePipeline that pushes all the items in the github repo to the S3 bucket, but the issue there is that `index.html` (and all the other files for the site) are in `dist/` when I want them to be at the root of the bucket. So you have to go to `example-site.com/dist/index.html` to access the site when I want it so you only have to go to `example-site.com`

So TLDR: all the items in the github repo are pushed to the S3 bucket, but I want only the items in the `dist/` folder to be pushed and I want them to end up at the root of the bucket. Is there a way to do that? If not, is there a workaround so that the items in `example-site.com/dist` are served as if they were at `example-site.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code is lying like this

```
example-site.com/dist/index.html
```

and you want it to be like this so that index.html can be served as static website:

```
example-site.com/index.html
```

How about if you create a lambda function in CodePipeline which will execute immediately after the code gets checked out into S3 Bucket. Lambda function will run on your S3 bucket and copy the files one level up.

Something like below :

[image: CodePipeline which executes after checking out code]

Comment: That link is broken for me, but that sounds like it'll work. I'll need to look further into how to do a lambda function in Codepipeline, but thank you very much!

Comment: Which link you were referring to?. I tried to give you a way out so you will need to probably code for your lambda to satisfy your condition.